# Capture and use all image URLs in a SASS file with a view to using css-only preload

Tags: css, regex, sass

I have recently started using css-only image preloading of background-images for a project.

```
//preload images
body:after{  
    display: none;
    content: url(img01.png) url(img02.png);
}

//use images
li.one { background-image: (img01.png) }
li.two { background-image: (img02.png) }
```

I make my CSS files from SCSS, and was wondering if there would be some way I could use SASS to run through the file and create the body:after preload from the background-image URLs throughout the file?

If not, what would be your best solution, making a script to use Regex to do this step after the CSS file is compiled?

Comment: Do you mean that if you say something like `.foo { content: image_dir_contents('some_dir') }` that it would look at the contents of the `some_dir` directory and generate the list of images based on that?  How will Sass know what order the images should be listed?

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer. I am using background-images listed in my SCSS file. Most, if not all, browsers defer loading of background images until they are shown on screen - so sometimes there will be a delay before background images show. I have now amended the question.

Placing the links into a content property, even if hidden, forces the browser to load them.

Answer (score 2):

@yorbro solution works for this specific case but I think its better to use only a function to do this two things at once, add the image path to $preload-images list and returns the value. Here is the `preload-img()` function:

```
// This declare a list variable to store all images to preload
$preloaded-images: ();

// This function will append the image or images to $preload-images and returns img path values
@function preload-img($img-path) {
    $output: ();
    @each $img in $img-path {
        $preloaded-images: append($preloaded-images, url($img));
        $output: append($output, url($img), comma);
    }
    @return $output;
}
```

With this function you can use background or background-image property and you can pass more than one image path to create multiple backgrounds. As @yorbro says you should add `body:after` at the end of your entire CSS:

```
// Use images, you can use background or background-image
// Note that you can pass a list of paths to preload-image function
li.one { background: preload-img("img01.png" "img02.png"); }
li.two { background-image: preload-img("img02.png"); }

//preload images
body:after{
    display: none;
    content: $preloaded-images;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SASS mixins, functions and lists for that. First, you create a mixin `background-image` that will add a `background-image` property and will append the image to a SASS list `preload-images`.

```
/* '$img-path' is in your case 'img01.png' or 'img02.png' */
@mixin background-image($img-path) {
  background-image: url($img-path);
  $tmp: preload-image($img-path);
}
```

Then you define the function `preload-image` along with a list `$preloaded-images`. The function appends `url($img-path)` to the `$preloaded-images` list.

```
/* Preloaded images */
$preloaded-images: null;
@function preload-image($image-path) {
  $preloaded-images: $preloaded-images url($image-url);
  @return $preloaded-images;
}
```

Every time you want to use a background image, you use the `background-image` mixin. Then, **at the end of your entire CSS file**, you add the `body:after` expression. This is important because you need to have added all the preloaded images to the list before outputting the `body:after` expression. So

```
//use images
li.one { @include background-image("img01.png"); }
li.two { @include background-image("img02.png"); }

//preload images
body:after{  
  display: none;
  content: $preloaded-images;
}
```

Conclusion: SASS as a language is limited in some ways but still powerful enough to realise these kind of nice things!